# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' to 'NSDictionary' + displaying annotations in a map view

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I really need help with an issue I'm getting when trying to parse a JSON that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvwZL.jpg
It's an array '[]' of dictionaries '{}', each dictionary have two key/value pairs, as seen in the picture.
This is my code, and I don't know why it crashes on line

```
for location in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Here is the code that's making it crash

```
func populateMapObjects() {

    if populatingMapObjects {
        return
    }

    populatingMapObjects = true

    self.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.MapObjects).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)) {

                if (JSON .isKindOfClass(NSArray)) {


                    for location in JSON as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                        if let issueLocation: IssueLocation = IssueLocation(locationName: "Center of the universe", campusName: "Queen's University", latitude: 44.22661586877309, longitude: -76.49380087852478, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.22661586877309, longitude: -76.49380087852478)) {

                            var index = 0

                            if let locationName = JSON[index]["name"] as? String {
                                issueLocation.locationName = locationName
                            }

                            print(issueLocation.locationName)

                            if let latitude = JSON[index]["coordinates"]!![1] as? Double {
                                issueLocation.latitude = latitude
                            }

                            if let longitude = JSON[index]["coordinates"]!![0] as? Double {
                                issueLocation.longitude = longitude
                            }

                            issueLocation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: issueLocation.latitude, longitude: issueLocation.longitude)

                            index++

                            self.mapObjects.addObject(issueLocation)
                    }
                }
            }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.populatingMapObjects = false
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm really confused regarding whether or not I should consider each "layer" of the JSON as an array or a dictionary, and if it should be NSDictionary, Dictionary.. and if I should use indexes or valueForKey.... I'm lost. Someone please tell me how to fix this bug.
I'm using the same API for other parts of the app but this view in particular gets a JSON that looks different, which is why I'm having trouble getting my code to work.

**EDIT 1: Code that adds the annotations to the map view.**

```
    func loadObjectsIntoMapView() {

    for mapObject in mapObjects {

        let temporaryMapAnnotation = IssueLocation(locationName: mapObject.locationName, campusName: "Main Campus", latitude: mapObject.latitude, longitude: mapObject.longitude, coordinate: mapObject.coordinate)

        if (temporaryMapAnnotation.longitude < -76.50921821594238) {
            temporaryMapAnnotation.campusName = "West Campus"
        }

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(temporaryMapAnnotation)
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like coordinates is an array.

Comment: Yeah which is why I'm using indices to get the latitude and longitude values. Is anything wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of dictionaries.  Your problem is this line:

```
for location in JSON as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
```

This should be:

```
for location in JSON as! [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
```

which can also be written as:

```
for location in JSON as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
```

The cast in this case applies to `JSON`; you are not casting the object that is being retrieved from the JSON array.

When you do this, `location` will have the type `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>` (also known as `[String: AnyObject]`).

Comment: You beat me to it! :)

Comment: I understand what you're saying and just changed my code, however my loop seems to be looping through the wrong thing. I've got a print statement on the "issueLocation.locationName" variable as you can see in my code. It keeps print "ARC" which is the name for the very first dictionary, so it seem to me like it's not iterating through each dictionary properly. Do you know why that is ?

Comment: Woah, I am an absolute idiot. I just realized that I was resetting the index value to 0 at every iteration....

Comment: Alright so I'm getting the objects correctly, thanks to you (I've been struggling with this for hours...). Now I just have to make sure that everything loads up into my mapView properly :) I'll comment here if I can't solve this issue myself (nothing is loading up on the map)! Thanks

Comment: Just use `location` instead of `JSON[index]`.  `location` picks up one value from the JSON array each loop.

Comment: So I indeed have a problem displaying my annotation on the map. I added the code as an edit. Can you help me make the annotations display correctly ? They were displaying fine when I was using static data, but now that I am using dynamic data from an API, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @LéonardBonfils, you should post a new question since this is not directly related to the original question.  That way you'll reach a wider range of eyes for your issue.

Comment: I just did :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558064/why-are-my-annotations-not-appearing-in-my-map-view

Answer (score 2):

I'm still learning the finer points of Swift myself.

My guess is that in this statement:

```
for location in JSON as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```

The operator precedence is this:

```
for location in (JSON as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
```

Which would force cast JSON to be a dictionary, and then try to do a for loop on it's contents.

Seem to me what you want is something like this:

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = JSON as! [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
for location in arrayOfDictionaries
```

That should cast your JSON object to a variable with specific types (an array of dictionaries of type `Dictionary<String,AnyObject>` and then do a for loop in that array.